# while loop not looping with str_pad

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently trying to do a loop where it will display all the records in the table. but the result that i get now is it display one data which the last record from the table. what should i do if i want to make it display all the records in table and not only one data being display

```
        $myFile = "testFile.txt";
        $fo = fopen($myFile, 'w' ) or die ("cant open file");

        $header = str_pad($rekod,0).str_pad($organisasi,5).str_pad($jabatan,40).str_pad($tarikh_kredit,8).str_pad($sec_code,16,"0").str_pad($filler,150)."\n";


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pengerusi_johor WHERE negeri='$negeri'";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        $detail = str_pad($rekod,0).str_pad($bank_code,7).str_pad($row['nombor_akaun'],16).str_pad($row['nama'],40);

        }

        fwrite($fo,trim($header).PHP_EOL.$detail);
        fclose($fo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are overwriting the value of `$detail` each time round the loop with the value in while  ..

you should use `.=` to append each row to your string

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   $detail .= str_pad($rekod,0).str_pad($bank_code,7).str_pad($row['nombor_akaun'],16).
           str_pad($row['nama'],40);

}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly  thanks for editing  ..  English writing improvement